# Why is component being disposed in params change?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-components, knockout-3.2

According to [ko's component documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html#component-lifecycle) on a component lifecycle:

> If the component binding’s name value changes observably, or if an
>   enclosing control-flow binding causes the container element to be
>   removed, then any dispose function on the viewmodel is called just
>   before the container element is removed from the DOM

I am not sure why my component is being disposed on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3e3g31o/1/).

```
<div data-bind='component: { name: "some-component", params: foo }'>
    <p data-bind="text: name"></p> 
</div>
```

```
function ComponentViewModel(params) {
}

ComponentViewModel.prototype.dispose = function() {
    console.log('disposing...');
};

ko.components.register('some-component', {
    viewModel: ComponentViewModel, 
    template : '<div></div>'
});

var rootvm = {
    foo : ko.observable('1')
};

ko.applyBindings(rootvm);

setTimeout(function() {
    rootvm.foo('2'); // this is disposing ComponentViewModel, why ??
}, 3000);
```

I can't see any of above's points in the documentation occurring on my fiddle. I certainly don't expect a `component` to be `disposed` and `re-instantiated` if the `params` injected change.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing component parameters in the wrong way: KnockoutJs requires an object with keys and values, you are passing in an observable. I didn't dig into the details of why that ends up triggering disposal, but if you pass an object as it expects, the dispose function is not invoked anymore.

```
<div data-bind='component: { name: "some-component", params: {foo: foo} }'>
    <p data-bind="text: name"></p> 
</div>
```